# Subscribing an Action to any event type via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, events, reflection, delegates

Consider:

```
someControl.Click += delegate { Foo(); };
```

The arguments of the event are irrelevant, I don't need them and I'm not interested in them. I just want Foo() to get called. There's no obvious way to do the same via reflection.

I'd like to translate the above into something along the lines of

```
void Foo() { /* launch missiles etc */ }

void Bar(object obj, EventInfo info)
{
    Action callFoo = Foo;
    info.AddEventHandler(obj, callFoo);
}
```

Also, I don't want to make the assumption that the type of object passed to Bar strictly adheres to the guidelines of using the EventHander(TArgs) signature for events. To put it simply, I'm looking for a way to subscribe an Action to any handler type; less simply, a way to convert the Action delegate into a delegate of the expected handler type.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the delegate type used for the event had a non-void return type, or an `out` parameter?

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point, I didn't really consider it; out parameters and return values aren't really useful for events. But I would expect a conversion error, an exception, etc. Basically I'd like to assume that those types wouldn't be used as event handlers for my own sanity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
static void AddEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo, object item,  Action action)
{
  var parameters = eventInfo.EventHandlerType
    .GetMethod("Invoke")
    .GetParameters()
    .Select(parameter => Expression.Parameter(parameter.ParameterType))
    .ToArray();

  var handler = Expression.Lambda(
      eventInfo.EventHandlerType, 
      Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(action), "Invoke", Type.EmptyTypes), 
      parameters
    )
    .Compile();

  eventInfo.AddEventHandler(item, handler);
}
static void AddEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo, object item, Action<object, EventArgs> action)
{
  var parameters = eventInfo.EventHandlerType
    .GetMethod("Invoke")
    .GetParameters()
    .Select(parameter => Expression.Parameter(parameter.ParameterType))
    .ToArray();

  var invoke = action.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke");

  var handler = Expression.Lambda(
      eventInfo.EventHandlerType,
      Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(action), invoke, parameters[0], parameters[1]),
      parameters
    )
    .Compile();

  eventInfo.AddEventHandler(item, handler);
}
```

Usage:

```
  Action action = () => BM_21_Grad.LaunchMissle();

  foreach (var eventInfo in form.GetType().GetEvents())
  {
    AddEventHandler(eventInfo, form, action);
  }
```

Comment: Ah, confusing, but it works! And made me realize the awesomeness of expressions (I never had a reason to use them). I haven't tested this thoroughly but I think I have what I need. Thanks ;)

Comment: I was searching for two days :) Thank you, thank you very much :)))

Comment: But I have a question. When I changed Action to Action<object,EventArg> = (o,e) => ... , Its error.. Can you help me about this question?

Comment: @TCTarımKöyİşleri Check current variant

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
void Bar(object obj, EventInfo info)
{
    var parameters = info.EventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters()
        .Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType));

    var handler = Expression.Lambda(
        info.EventHandlerType,
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Constant(obj), // obj is the instance on which Foo()
            "Foo",                    // will be called
            null
        ),
        parameters
    );
    info.AddEventHandler(obj, handler.Compile());
}
```