# Add and remove event handler via reflection c#

Tags: c#, reflection

Good day!
My purpose is to implement class which will allow us subscribe and unsubscribe objects to(from) events. Here is the code of my class.

```
public static class EventSubscriber
{
    public static void AddEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo, object item, Action action)
    {
        var parameters = GetParameters(eventInfo);
        var handler = GetHandler(eventInfo, action, parameters);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(item, handler);
    }

    public static void RemoveEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo,
                        object item, Action action)
    {
        var parameters = GetParameters(eventInfo);
        var handler = GetHandler(eventInfo, action, parameters);
        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(item, handler);
    }

    private static ParameterExpression[] GetParameters(EventInfo eventInfo)
    {
        return eventInfo.EventHandlerType
          .GetMethod("Invoke")
          .GetParameters()
          .Select(parameter => Expression.Parameter(parameter.ParameterType))
          .ToArray();
    }

    private static Delegate GetHandler(EventInfo eventInfo,
                Action action, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda(
            eventInfo.EventHandlerType,
            Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(action),
                      "Invoke", Type.EmptyTypes), parameters)
          .Compile();
    }
}
```

As you can see here are 2 public methods which actually subscribe and unsubscribe objects to(from) event. And here is the sample how I test it

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.SubscribeTimer();
        while (true)
        {
            if(test.a == 10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        test.UnsubscribeTimer();
        while (true)
        {

        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer;
    public int a = 0;

    public Test()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void SubscribeTimer()
    {
        var eventInfo = typeof(System.Timers.Timer).GetEvent("Elapsed");
        EventSubscriber.AddEventHandler(eventInfo, timer, TimerElapsed);
        EventSubscriber.RemoveEventHandler(eventInfo, timer, TimerNotElapsed);
    }

    public void UnsubscribeTimer()
    {
        var eventInfo = typeof(System.Timers.Timer).GetEvent("Elapsed");
        EventSubscriber.AddEventHandler(eventInfo, timer, TimerNotElapsed);
        EventSubscriber.RemoveEventHandler(eventInfo, timer, TimerElapsed);
    }

    public void TimerElapsed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("timer elapsed");
        a++;
    }

    public void TimerNotElapsed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("timer not elapsed");
        a++;
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour of sample is that on the begining we will see the message "timer elapsed" every second, after 10-th second we should see only "timer not elapsed" and we do, but we still see "timer elapsed" too. This means that AddEventHandler method works, but RemoveEventHandler method doesn't.

I would be very happy if you will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order for an event handler to be removed, the delegate must be an exact match.  Same Method and Target properties.  The Target is not the same.  Very hard to see btw, the Closure object is heavily obfuscated by Expression.Lambda().  Cute trick but I seriously doubt you can make it work.  Also note that you are violating threading requirements, you cannot assume you can see any updates to the a variable.

Comment: Thanks for reply! So, if I will make signature of event handler the same as signature of delegate type of event I will be able to unsubscribe as I wrote it in my sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you are creating a new handler each time: *(which doesn't match the previous handler, so can't be removed from the invocation list)*

```
public static void RemoveEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo,
                    object item, Action action)
{
    var parameters = GetParameters(eventInfo);
    var handler = GetHandler(eventInfo, action, parameters); // <--
    eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(item, handler);
}
```

Why are you wrapping the `Action`? To lose the parameters? It is not possible to add/remove the `eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(item, action);` because of the parameters. If you want to remove a newly generated handler, you should return that handler when you want to remove it.

```
public static Delegate AddEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo, object item, Action action)
{
    var parameters = GetParameters(eventInfo);
    var handler = GetHandler(eventInfo, action, parameters);
    eventInfo.AddEventHandler(item, handler);
    return handler;
}

public static void RemoveEventHandler(EventInfo eventInfo,
                    object item, Delegate handler)
{
    eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(item, handler);
}
```

---

```
var handler = EventSubscriber.AddEventHandler(eventInfo, timer, TimerElapsed);

EventSubscriber.RemoveEventHandler(eventInfo, timer, handler);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. But I didn't catch you what you meant when asked "Why are you wrapping the Action? To lose the what parameters? It is not possible to add/remove the eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(item, action); because of the parameters.". I would be very grateful if you will explain it to me, or maybe you can give me some links what I have read to understand it.

Comment: In short: The `Timer.Elapsed` event type is `EventHandler` meaning: when you want to receive events, your event handler/method must match the event type..  `void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Your action doesn't match the definition, so using `Expression.Lambda` you will create a new method, that does match the event `Timer.Elapsed` definition, and will call your parameterless `Action`. So it will wrap your Action. The thing is, you'll need to unsubscribe the delegate created from the `Expression.Lambda` instead of the Action it self, because that one was added to the invocationlist.

Comment: So, it's good if we don't want use our parameters (object sender and EventArgs e), because our code (I mean our event handler) looks clearer (at least for me). But if I want use these parameters in my event handler I should create this method with necessary paratemers and in EventSubscriber.AddEventHandler() I will subscribe my Action (not delegate created from the Expression.Lambda). If signature of handler will match to signature of delegate I will be able unsubscribe as I wrote in my sample? Am I right?

Comment: If you want to add a handler without the `Expression.Lambda`, you should instead passing an `Action` pass an `EventHandler` type. Then you don't need the `Expression.Lambda. And you could unsubscribe the handler directly. Where did you leeched this code? ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I think I caught you. My main purpose as I wrote was create Subscriber class which will subscribe and unsubscribe any object on(from) any event and I found this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753366/subscribing-an-action-to-any-event-type-via-reflection

Answer (score 2):

Had to stitch a bunch of sources together to get what I needed which was a one-stop extension method (that could be easily modified if we switched component vendors) to simply clear all existing Event Handlers on an Event we did not control.

Usage is simple:

```
thirdPartyControlInstance.ClearEventHandlers(nameof(ThirdPartyControlType.ToolClick));
```

Here is the code, any suggestions to make it more robust/efficient/cleaner are welcome:

```
public static class EventExtensions
{
    public static void ClearEventHandlers(this object obj, string eventName)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var objType = obj.GetType();
        var eventInfo = objType.GetEvent(eventName);
        if (eventInfo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var isEventProperty = false;
        var type = objType;
        FieldInfo eventFieldInfo = null;
        while (type != null)
        {
            /* Find events defined as field */
            eventFieldInfo = type.GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (eventFieldInfo != null && (eventFieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(MulticastDelegate) || eventFieldInfo.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MulticastDelegate))))
            {
                break;
            }

            /* Find events defined as property { add; remove; } */
            eventFieldInfo = type.GetField("EVENT_" + eventName.ToUpper(), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (eventFieldInfo != null)
            {
                isEventProperty = true;
                break;
            }

            type = type.BaseType;
        }

        if (eventFieldInfo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (isEventProperty)
        {
            // Default Events Collection Type
            RemoveHandler<EventHandlerList>(obj, eventFieldInfo);
            // Infragistics Events Collection Type
            RemoveHandler<EventHandlerDictionary>(obj, eventFieldInfo);
            return;
        }

        if (!(eventFieldInfo.GetValue(obj) is Delegate eventDelegate))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Remove Field based event handlers
        foreach (var d in eventDelegate.GetInvocationList())
        {
            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(obj, d);
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveHandler<T>(object obj, FieldInfo eventFieldInfo)
    {
        var objType = obj.GetType();
        var eventPropertyValue = eventFieldInfo.GetValue(obj);

        if (eventPropertyValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var propertyInfo = objType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Events" && p.PropertyType == typeof(T));
        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var eventList = propertyInfo?.GetValue(obj, null);
        switch (eventList) {
            case null:
                return;
            case EventHandlerDictionary typedEventList:
                typedEventList.RemoveHandler(eventPropertyValue, typedEventList[eventPropertyValue]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Can the code be changed to clear event handlers in a STATIC class? I want to clear all the event handlers of a static class. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149903/how-to-clear-all-static-event-handlers-in-a-class-via-reflection)