# C# reflection: How to subscribe to a event without knowing delegate signature?

Tags: c#, generics, events, reflection, delegates

I'd like to construct a little adapter class with which a run-time interpreter may intercept the occurance of events regardless of delegate type.

I've tried something like this (which fails with a runtime-exception in the constructor):

```
public class ModelEvent
{
    private object source;
    private EventInfo sourceEvent;
    private Delegate eventHandler;
    public event EventHandler OnEvent;

    public ModelEvent(object source, EventInfo sourceEvent)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.sourceEvent = sourceEvent;

        // this line is responsible for the error,
        // the signatures of the eventHandler and delegate method don't match
        this.eventHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            this.sourceEvent.EventHandlerType,
            this,
            typeof(ModelEvent).GetMethod("OnSourceEvent"));
        // Alternative failed attempts
        // this.eventHandler = new Action<object, object> (this.OnSourceEvent);
        // this.eventHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler), this, typeof(ModelEvent).GetMethod("OnSourceEvent"));

        this.sourceEvent.AddEventHandler(this.source, this.eventHandler);
    }

    private void OnSourceEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
    {
        this.OnEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // ... truncated for clarity
}
```

This crashes at runtime, since the `(object, object)` signature of my `OnSourceEvent` method does not match any `(object, T)` signature of the generic `EventHandler<T>` delegate of the given event `sourceEvent`.

So I guess I need to construct some sort of wrapper with the correct signature at runtime?

I'm quite new at generics in C# and would appreciate any help in finding a way to construct a viable Delegate, if my interpretation is correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out Jon Skeet's blog post, MAKING REFLECTION FLY AND EXPLORING DELEGATES.

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/

Comment: Look into [MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reading material. However, I've found the solution to my problem [in this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638812/add-and-remove-event-handler-via-reflection-c-sharp).

The trick is to dynamically create a lambda-expressions at runtime to wrap my "parameterless" events and use that as the delegate.

The correct code looks like this. Using it, you can subscribe to any event and get notified when it is raised (although you won't get any `EventArgs`):

```
public class ModelEvent
{
    private object source;
    private EventInfo sourceEvent;
    private Delegate eventHandler;
    public event EventHandler OnEvent;

    public ModelEvent(object source, EventInfo sourceEvent)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.sourceEvent = sourceEvent;
        ParameterExpression[] sourceEventHandlerParameters =
            sourceEvent
            .EventHandlerType
            .GetMethod("Invoke")
            .GetParameters()
            .Select(parameter => Expression.Parameter(parameter.ParameterType))
            .ToArray();
        MethodCallExpression fireOnEvent = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Constant(new Action(FireOnEvent)),
            "Invoke",
            Type.EmptyTypes);
        this.eventHandler = Expression.Lambda(
            sourceEvent.EventHandlerType,
            fireOnEvent,
            sourceEventHandlerParameters)
            .Compile();
        this.sourceEvent.AddEventHandler(this.source, this.eventHandler);
    }

    private void FireOnEvent()
    {
        this.OnEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

If you know your way around the `Expression` class I guess you can eliminate the `FireOnEvent` method and somehow directly call `this.OnEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)`, but I was too lazy to figure out how to construct that call dynamically.