# How to clear all static event handlers in a class via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have STATIC class with lots of static event callbacks. Instead of hard coding a reset method, I want to use reflection to automatically clear all the event subscriptions.

```
public static void NotifyA(int p1) { notifyA?.Invoke(p1); }
public static event Action<int> notifyA;

public static void NotifyB(float p1) { notifyB?.Invoke(p1); }
public static event Action<float> notifyB;

// and so on...
```

I am stuck at this stage don't know how to actually clear the events.

```
    public static void ResetEvents()
    {
        var type = typeof(ClientEvents);

        var events = type.GetEvents(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var current in events )
        {
            // current.RemoveEventHandler(???);

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638812/add-and-remove-event-handler-via-reflection-c-sharp)

Comment: @styx The problem is my class is a static class. The code sample there require me to pass a class instance to the helper function.

Comment: Honestly, static events are almost always a bad idea in the first place; and removing *other code's* subscriptions is not great either. But you *should* usually be able to simply pass null to any reflection API for static members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general**, it doesn't make sense to "remove all subscribers" of an event in .NET. Events don't even need to remember who their subscribers are! An event really is just a pair of methods, called `add` and `remove`, that take some type of delegate as parameters, and you can do whatever you want in those methods, e.g.

```
public static event Action<int> MySillyEvent {
    add {
        Console.WriteLine($"{value.Method.Name} is being added!");
    }
    remove {
        Console.WriteLine($"{value.Method.Name} is being removed!");
    }
}
```

Now tell me, what would "remove all subscribers from `MySillyEvent`" even mean?

If you limit your scope, to just [field-like events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#field-like-events), which are events that are backed by a delegate field, then this is a more tractable problem. You just need to set the delegate field that's backing the event to null. Your `notifyA` and `notifyB` events are field-like events.

However, the names of the delegate fields are implementation-dependent, and `EventInfo` doesn't know whether it is field-like or not.

If your class doesn't have any explicitly declared static delegate fields, you can just find all the non-public, static fields of a delegate type in your class:

```
var fields = typeof(ClientEvents).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(x => x.FieldType.BaseType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)));
foreach (var field in fields) {
    field.SetValue(null, null);
}
```

Otherwise, you need to rely on some implementation details, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638812/add-and-remove-event-handler-via-reflection-c-sharp) does. We assume that the field name is the same as the event's name. This is at least true with the compiler that I'm using.

```
var type = typeof(ClientEvents);
var fields = type.GetEvents(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(e => type.GetField(e.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
foreach (var field in fields) {
    field.SetValue(null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `ResetEvents` method is in the same static class, then you don't even need reflection:

```cs
//public static event Action<int> notifyA;
private static Action<int> notifyAHandler;
public static event Action<int> NotifyA
{
    add => notifyAHandler += value;
    remove => notifyAHandler -= value;
}


public static void ResetEvents()
{
    notifyAHandler = null;
    // ...
}
```

If you really want to use reflection, then iterate the static fields of delegate types instead, and set them to null.

**Remark:** Conventionally, all event with data should use the `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate, even if `sender` is `null` for a static event.

Comment: This is actually what I am doing. The problem of this approach vs using reflection is that when a new even handler is added, there is a chance I forget to add a corresponding set null  in the Reset function.